# CSS relative positioned elements, intentional overlap?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have two divs inside a parent div that I'd like to be relatively positioned. The only thing is that I'd like for one div to fill up 100% of the parent and to overlap the second div, which I'd like to fill up 50% of the parent, but be right aligned. If I decrease the width of the first div, then, the second div would become visible without ever having to be hidden.

How can it be done?

Comment: you'll have to position one of them absolute

Comment: you will just need to set the z-Index to set the 2nd div behind

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with relative positioning, it'll have to be absolute:

http://jsfiddle.net/WKJwk/

Comment: I agree with you answer - but only the 50% div needs to be absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/NPV5C/